# Add & remove custom layout element in Activity Java code

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-intent

I have a main **activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

              //HOW TO: dynamically add or remove <com.my.custom.MyCustomLayout>
        }
}
```

The content of the above main **Activity** is:

**main.xml**

```
<FrameLayout ...>

    <LinearLayout ...>

    <com.my.custom.MyCustomLayout
          android:id="@+id/custom">

<FrameLayout>
```

As you see above, I have a **custom layout** element, which is a Java class extends `LinearLayout` like following:

```
public class MyCustomLayout extends LinearLayout{
          ...
}
```

In my **activity** java code, I would like to dynamically **add or remove** the custom layout element`<com.my.custom.MyCustomLayout>` in **main.xml** layout.
How to do it in My activity Java code?

Comment: you can do it by giving id to your layout elements and use addView and removeChildView()

Comment: Hi, Android Killer, thank you, could you please be more detailed, better with some sample code, and make it an answer?

Comment: Little bit busy dear.I will try to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Create a different layout file with your custom view like:

```
difflayout.xml:

<com.my.custom.MyCustomLayout
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/custom">
```

Take a reference of your container LinearLayout on your code section. Use `LayoutInflater` and `addView()` and `removeAllViews()` of the `ViewGroup` class(here your `LinearLayout`)

Answer (score 1):

First consider if you really want to remove the view from the layout or just completely hide it. You need to have a very good reason to go for the latter.

To just hide the view you would do in your activity

```
findViewById(R.id.custom).setVisibility(View.GONE) // to hide
// or
findViewById(R.id.custom).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) // to show
```

If you really want to completely remove the view from the layout, you can

```
View customView = findViewById(R.id.custom);
ViewGroup parentView = (ViewGroup) customView.getParent();
parentView.removeView(customView)
```

Answer (score 0):

you must have defined , id for the custom layout. use this id in java code
example : `customLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(id);`
now with customLayout call the layout

Comment: yes, I know I need to have id, just for get to add to layout elements. But my concern is how to add and remove my custom layout element in Java code